# Using name binding annotations in Jersey

Tags: java, rest, jersey

How does the `@NameBinding` annotation work in Jersey to apply a filter on particular resource methods or resource class?

Consider the following annotation:

```java
@NameBinding
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
public @interface SomeAnnotaion{}
```

How does it work?

Comment: Are you asking how does it work under the hood? Or just how to use it?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

### Name binding

*Name binding* is a concept that allows to say to a JAX-RS runtime that a specific filter or interceptor will be executed only for a specific resource method. When a filter or an interceptor is limited only to a specific resource method we say that it is *name-bound*. Filters and interceptors that do not have such a limitation are called *global*.

### Defining a name binding annotation

Filters or interceptors can be assigned to a resource method using the [`@NameBinding`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/NameBinding.html) annotation. This annotation is used as meta annotation for other user implemented annotations that are applied to a providers and resource methods. See the following example:

```java
@NameBinding
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Compress {}
```

The example above defines a new `@Compress` annotation which is a name binding annotation as it is annotated with [`@NameBinding`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/NameBinding.html). The `@Compress` annotation can be used to bind filters and interceptor to endpoints.

### Binding a filter or interceptor to an endpoint

Consider you have an interceptor that performs GZIP compression and you want to bind such interceptor to a resource method. To do it, annotate both the resource method and the interceptor, as following:

```java
@Compress
public class GZIPWriterInterceptor implements WriterInterceptor {

    @Override
    public void aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorContext context)
                    throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
        final OutputStream outputStream = context.getOutputStream();
        context.setOutputStream(new GZIPOutputStream(outputStream));
        context.proceed();
    }
}
```

```java
@Path("helloworld")
public class HelloWorldResource {

    @GET
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String getHello() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }

    @GET
    @Path("too-much-data")
    @Compress
    public String getVeryLongString() {
        String str = ... // very long string
        return str;
    }
}
```

The `@Compress` is applied on the resource method `getVeryLongString()` and on the interceptor `GZIPWriterInterceptor`. The interceptor will be executed only if any resource method with such a annotation will be executed.

In above example, the interceptor will be executed only for the `getVeryLongString()` method. The interceptor will not be executed for method `getHello()`. In this example the reason is probably clear. We would like to compress only long data and we do not need to compress the short response of `"Hello World!"`.

Name binding can be applied on a resource class. In the example `HelloWorldResource` would be annotated with `@Compress`. This would mean that all resource methods will use compression in this case.

Note that global filters are executed always, so even for resource methods which have any name binding annotations.

### Documentation

- [`@NameBinding` annotation documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/NameBinding.html)
- [Jersey documentation about filters and interceptors](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html)

### Examples

- [Logging HTTP requests and responses using filters and name binding annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33667568/1426227)
- [Token-based authentication using filters and name binding annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26778123/1426227)
- [Using interceptors and name binding annotations to add a property to a JSON with Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36546268/1426227)
- [Filters with name binding for security purposes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33649605/1426227)

Comment: Can we add `Compress("ABC")` and get this "ABC" in `ContainerRequestFilter`?