# gZip Implementations in REST APIs

Tags: java, performance, jax-rs, gzip

How to use gzip filters with REST API?
Also, lets say I want to have a implementation at one place. Are there ways to configure out of like 20 APIs, only a few APIs use it.

Any documentation would be helpful.

Comment: Could you please clarify your question? I really don't know what you mean.

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin: edited. Please let me know if it clarifies your doubts

Comment: Could you show what you have tried so far?

Comment: Just have the REST API implementations. Was searching over the web for to understand how this could be done.

Comment: What's your JAX-RS implementation?

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin: Jersey

Comment: Jersey 1.x or 2.x? Please ensure you add such details in your next questions.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. New to stackoverflow. Jersey 2.x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be achieved with a [`WriterInterceptor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/WriterInterceptor.html):

```java
public class GZIPWriterInterceptor implements WriterInterceptor {

    @Override
    public void aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorContext context)
                throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
        final OutputStream outputStream = context.getOutputStream();
        context.setOutputStream(new GZIPOutputStream(outputStream));
        context.proceed();
    }
}
```

Then register the [`WriterInterceptor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/WriterInterceptor.html) in your [`ResourceConfig`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.22.2/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ResourceConfig.html) / [`Application`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Application.html) subclass:

```java
@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {

    public MyApplication() {
        register(GZIPWriterInterceptor.class);
    }
}
```

To bind the interceptor to certain resource methods or classes, you could use [name binding annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38523942/1426227).

For further details, check the [Jersey documentation about filters and interceptors](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html).

Comment: It works. although you might need to add the header in the response