# Jersey 2 status code not visible in HttpServletResponseWrapper

Tags: java, jersey, servlet-filters, http-status-codes, servlet-2.5

The Java servlet API does not provide a getStatus method for HttpServletResponse until version 3.0. I have created a HttpServletResponseWrapper with getStatus to wrap HttpServletResponse and catch the status when it is set.

This does not work with my Jersey 2 servlet.

My HttpServletResponseWrapper is passed via the doFilter(request, wrapperResponse) of my Filter. The Filter is called but the getStatus method is not called when a Jersey RESTful Servlet is the endpoint.

Is there any configuration I have missed?

I use the response builder to return the result and set the status.

Response.status(404).build();
Response.status(200).type(mediaType).entity(theEntity).build();

Best Regards
Jochen

Comment: What do you need a `HttpServletResponseWrapper` for?

Comment: To get the status code for the gzip filter, no gzip header on 404 or 204 responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a [`HttpServletResponseWrapper`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponseWrapper.html) for GZIP compression. It could be achieved with a [`WriterInterceptor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/WriterInterceptor.html) from JAX-RS:

```java
public class GZIPWriterInterceptor implements WriterInterceptor {

    @Override
    public void aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorContext context)
                throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
        final OutputStream outputStream = context.getOutputStream();
        context.setOutputStream(new GZIPOutputStream(outputStream));
        context.proceed();
    }
}
```

Then register the [`WriterInterceptor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/WriterInterceptor.html) in your [`ResourceConfig`](https://jersey.github.io/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ResourceConfig.html) / [`Application`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Application.html) subclass:

```java
@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {

    public MyApplication() {
        register(GZIPWriterInterceptor.class);
    }
}
```

To bind the interceptor to certain resource methods or classes, you could use [name binding annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38523942/1426227).

Comment: Got it working. That WriterInterceptor is only triggered when I send an entity is great, so my 404 and 204 case is covered. But how can I skip this gzip if the request does not have the Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br header?

Comment: @ScubaInstructor You should be able to inject the request headers in your interceptor using `@Context HttpHeaders httpHeaders`.

Comment: I will go now with this solution  EncodingFilter.enableFor(this, GZipEncoder.class, DeflateEncoder.class); and skip the WriterInterceptor.